# how to organize an undefined data set

Tags: csv

I have a data1.csv file with 74 rows containing names and about 300 columns containing dates.

I used the following codes:

```
data1<-read.csv(data1.csv)
names(data1)[1]<-paste("name")
```

So, the data looks like the following:

```
name    v2          v3          etc      v300    
        2011/08/01  2011/08/02  etc      2014/03/03
name1   123         132         etc      134 
name2   12          14          etc      15
```

etc

For each name (name1 to name 74), data is for each date. I don't need V2-V300 - just want to name the second row as "date". How can I transpose data by each name such that the data looks like the following:

```
name       date        data
name1      2011/08/01  123 
name1      2011/08/02  132
etc        etc         etc
name2      2011/08/01  12
name2      2011/08/02  14
etc        etc         etc
```

Thanks in advance,

chw

Comment: what is the programming language that you use?

Comment: ??  what is the programming language that you use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AWK: Converting CSV with Headers to Summary Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22367072/awk-converting-csv-with-headers-to-summary-table)