# AWK: Converting CSV with Headers to Summary Table

Tags: csv, awk

I have a need to document 100+ CSV files as far as the format of those files and including sample data.   What I would like to do is take a CSV of the following format:

```
Name, Phone, State
Fred, 1234567, TX
John, 2345678, NC
```

and convert it to:

```
Field | Sample
---   | ----
Name  | Fred
Phone | 1234567
State | TX
```

Is this possible with AWK?   From my example below, you will see I am trying to format as a markdown table. I have it currently transposing the header row with

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -v RS='\r\n' -f
BEGIN { printf "| Field \t| Critical |\n"}
{
    printf "|---\t|---\t|\n"
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {print "|", toupper($i), "| sample |"}
}
END  {}
```

But I am not sure now how to use the first row of data, after the header to display the sample data?

Comment: can you give two samples in output at least?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` is the right tool for data parsing. You can try something like:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=", "; OFS=" | " }
NR==1 {
    for(tag = 1; tag <= NF; tag++) {
        hdr[tag] = sprintf ("%-7s", $tag)
    }
    next
}
{
    for(fld = 1; fld <= NF; fld++) {
        data[NR,fld] = $fld
    }
}
END {
    print "Field   | Sample\n------- | -------";
    for(rec = 2; rec <= NR; rec++) {
        for(line = 1; line <= NF; line++) {
            print hdr[line], data[rec,line]
        }
    }
}' file
```

**Output**:

```
Field   | Sample
------- | -------
Name    | Fred
Phone   | 1234567
State   | TX
Name    | John
Phone   | 2345678
State   | NC
```

Comment: Spot on, thank you so much!  This is exactly what I was after.   I love the Internet and all who share their knowledge on it!  Thanks.

Comment: Since you are using `tag` value only one loop, you can replace `for(tag = 1; tag <= NF; tag++)` with `while(tag++<NF)`

Comment: @Jotne Indeed, just went with the more explicit version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more simple way to do it with `awk`
No need to store everything in a array then print at the end.

```
awk -F", " 'NR==1{split($0,a,FS);print "Field   | Sample\n------- | -------";next} {for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%-8s| %s\n",a[i],$i}' file
Field   | Sample
------- | -------
Name    | Fred
Phone   | 1234567
State   | TX
Name    | John
Phone   | 2345678
State   | NC
```

How it works:

```
awk -F", " '                            # set field separator to ","
NR==1{                                  # if first line do:
    split($0,a,FS)                      # split first line to an array named "a" to get the labels 
    print "Field   | Sample"            # print header
    print "------- | -------"           # print separator
    next}                               # prevents nothing more run for first line
    {                                   # for all lines except first do:
    for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)                 # loop trough all element in line
        printf "%-8s| %s\n",a[i],$i     # print data for every element
    }
' file
```